# Evaluate $\int_cydx+zdy+zdz$ if c is intersection of upper hemisphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=4$ $z \geq0$ and $x^2+y^2=2x$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-forms, line-integrals, stokes-theorem

**Evaluate $\int_cydx+zdy+zdz$ if c is intersection of upper hemisphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=4$ $z \geq0$ and $x^2+y^2=2x$ oriented counter clockwise from xy plane**

First, I made the following parametricisation:
$$g(x,y) = \begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\ \sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}\end{bmatrix}$$

naturally, I set $\omega=ydx+zdy+xdz$. This is where I am getting stumped. I want to evaluate $\int_Dg^*dw$ but I'm not sure how to get dw?

I did something janky: $d\omega = dy\wedge dx +dz\wedge dy + dx\wedge dz$. First of all, that doesn't seem right. Secondly, if it were, what would $g^*\omega$ be??

Comment: Is z-component $z$ or $x$? As per question, it says $z$ but you have used $x$ somewhere in your work. I have answered assuming it is $z$ as given in the question.

Answer (score 2):

You need to parametrize the curve which is intersection of the cylinder and the upper hemisphere. You have instead parametrized the spherical surface.

First note that the projection of the cylinder  $x^2 + y^2 = 2x$ in xy-plane is a circle centered at $(1, 0)$, y-axis is tangent to it and it is formed in fourth and first quadrant.

Now in polar coordinates, $r^2 = 2 r \cos\theta \implies r = 2 \cos\theta$

That gives $x = 1 + \cos2\theta, y = \sin2\theta$

Also at the intersection, $2x + z^2 = 4 \implies z = \sqrt{4-2x} = 2 \mid\sin\theta \mid $

So for the intersection curve below $y = 0$, we can use the parametrization $ \displaystyle \vec r(\theta) = (1 + \cos2\theta, \sin2\theta, - 2 \sin\theta), -\pi/2 \leq \theta \leq 0$ and above $y = 0$, we can use the parametrization
$ \displaystyle \vec r(\theta) = (1 + \cos2\theta, \sin2\theta, 2 \sin\theta), 0 \leq \theta \leq \pi/2$

As per question, $\vec F = (y, z, z)$

So, $\vec F(\vec r(\theta)) = (\sin2\theta,  - 2 \sin\theta, - 2\sin\theta)$ for $- \pi/2 \leq \theta \leq 0~$ and
$~\vec F(\vec r(\theta)) = (\sin2\theta,  2 \sin\theta, 2\sin\theta)$ for $0 \leq \theta \leq \pi/2$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Hello, I am working on this same problem and I have a question: with $r=2\cos(\theta)$, given that in polar coordinates $x$ should be $x=1+r\cos(\theta)$ shouldn't it be $x=2+\cos(2\theta)$ instead of $x=1+\cos(2\theta)$?

Comment: @lorenzo in polar coordinates, $x = r \cos \theta = 2 \cos^2\theta = 1 + \cos2\theta$

Comment: Pls note I am not shifting the origin to $(1, 0)$. That's why $x^2 + y^2 = 2x$ gives $r = 2 \cos\theta$.

Comment: Ah, I see, thank you. I have two more questions, if I may. (1) Why is $z=2\sin(\theta)$ and not $z=2|\sin(\theta)|$? (2) In general what is the thought process that you use to find parametrizations of curves? It seems to me that, apart from the most obvious cases, one would either (a) just consider the symmetry of the problem (like "circular" symmetry in this case) and then use the corresponding usual parametrization (polar coordinates) or (b) manipulate the system of equations in such a way to express all the coordinates in terms of one coordinate and then use that as a parameter.

Comment: I don't follow your second question well but for the first, you are absolutely correct! I wrote it incorrectly in a hurry. Thanks for your question that helped me correct my answer.

Comment: You are very welcome. I get, for $\vec{F}=(y,z,x),\ \int_{C}ydx+zdy+xdz=\int_{\theta=-\pi/2}^{\theta=0}\left(\sin(2\theta)(-2\sin(2\theta))+(-2\sin(\theta))(2\cos(2\theta))+(1+\cos(2\theta))(-2\cos(\theta))\right)d\theta+\int_{\theta=0}^{\theta=\pi/2}\left(\sin(2\theta)(-2\sin(2\theta))+(2\sin(\theta))(2\cos(2\theta))+(1+\cos(2\theta))(2\cos(\theta))\right)d\theta = \left(-2\cdot\frac{\pi}{4}-4\cdot\frac{1}{3}-2\cdot 1-2\cdot\frac{1}{3}\right)+\left(-2\cdot\frac{\pi}{4}-4\cdot\frac{1}{3}+2\cdot 1+2\cdot\frac{1}{3}\right)=-\pi-\frac{8}{3}$.

Comment: Yes if $\vec F = (y, z, x)$ then I get the same answer.

Answer (score 0):

You're proceeding just fine, as long as you realize you're going to want to integrable $d\omega$ on the portion of the *sphere* inside that curve. I would parametrize by polar coordinates to make life easier, but you'll end up there eventually.

Your formula for $d\omega$ is correct. Now pull back using your rules for pullback. $g^*dx = dx$, $g^*dy = dy$, $g^*dz = -(\frac x{\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}}\,dx + \frac y{\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}}\,dy)$. You should find that $g^*d\omega = -(\frac x{\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}}+\frac y{\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}}+1)dx\wedge dy$. Switching to polar coordinates, this will be
$$-\left(\frac{r(\cos\theta+\sin\theta)}{\sqrt{4-r^2}} + 1\right)r\,dr\wedge d\theta.$$
You do need to stop and think about orientations. Given the orientation specified on the curve, is the region interior to it on the sphere given the usual upward orientation or its negative? So, is your parametrization orientation-preserving or reversing? Perhaps the negative sign will go away.

Now, over what region in the $xy$-plane are you going to do the double integral, now that you've pulled back? Does thinking about symmetry simplify the calculation slightly?

**REMARK**: This does seem to be a yucky problem. It does now occur to me that it comes from my text (although different orientation). My intent was a direct calculation of the line integral, as in MathLover's answer.